# jta rollback not happening while running in jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jta, jdbctemplate

I have to maintain a transaction between two different data sources in an Oracle database using spring jdbc template. Below is my configuration for that.

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:jboss/TESTDB</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="mainDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:jboss/SELVADB</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="mainJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

I set `jta` true in `standalone.xml` but still the rollback doesn't happen. Below is my java code.

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public ResultBean saveUser() throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    userDao.saveEmailLog();
    userDao.saveUser();
    throw new Exception();
    //return new ResultBean();
}
```